# Отметить или снять отметку со всех чекбоксов с определенным классом

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Есть форма с чекбоксами, name у всех чекбоксов одинаков, но они разбиты на группы с помощью классов:

```
<form>
<input type="checkbox" name="name" class="chb_1" value="value_1" /> 
<input type="checkbox" name="name" class="chb_1" value="value_2" />
<input type="checkbox" name="name" class="chb_1" value="value_3" />
<button type="button" class="uncheck_1">Снять отметки 1</button>
<input type="checkbox" name="name" class="chb_2" value="value_4" />
<input type="checkbox" name="name" class="chb_2" value="value_5" />
<button type="button" class="uncheck_2">Снять отметки 2</button>
</form>
```

Нужно добавить кнопки, которые сбрасывают отмеченные чекбоксы с определенным классом. То есть кнопка `uncheck_1` сбрасывает только отмеченные чекбоксы с классом `chb_1`, а `uncheck_2` - только `chb_2`. Подскажите пожалуйста, как? Благодарю за помощь!

UPD если кнопка сброса будет автоматически переотправлять форму, то вообще шикарно!

Comment: А форма именно так и будет выглядеть?

Comment: @bonusrk ну в целом так, хотя там намного больше чекбоксов, и несколько input type=range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Формально, так:

```js
setFormFunctional();

function setFormFunctional() {
  let bubu = document.getElementById('bubu');

  toggleUncheckBtns();
  btnAppearOnChange();
  uncheckAllOnClick();

  function uncheckAllOnClick() {
    bubu.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      let num = (e.target.className.match(/uncheck_(\d+)/) || [0, 0])[1]; // (*1)
      if (num) {
        let cbs = document.querySelectorAll('.chb_' + num);
        cbs.forEach(cb => cb.checked = false);
        // Google → Стрелочные функции, Делегирование событий
        
        display(e.target, 'none');
      }
    });
  }

  function btnAppearOnChange() {
    let cbs = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="chb_"]');
    cbs.forEach(cb => {
      cb.addEventListener('change', toggleUncheckBtns);
    });
  }

  function toggleUncheckBtns() {
    let uncheckBtns = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="uncheck_"]');
    display(uncheckBtns, "none");

    let cbs = document.querySelectorAll('[class*="chb_"]');
    cbs.forEach(cb => {
      if (cb.checked) {
        let num = cb.className.match(/chb_(\d+)/)[1];
        let btn = document.querySelector(".uncheck_" + num);
        display(btn, "inline-block");
      }
    });
  }
}

function display(elems, value = "block") {
  if (elems instanceof HTMLElement) {
    return elems.style.display = value;
  }

  [...elems].forEach(elem => elem.style.display = value);
  // См → Spread Operator
}
```

```html
<form id="bubu">
  <input type="checkbox" name="name" class="chb_1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="name" class="chb_1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="name" class="chb_1" />
  <button type="button" class="uncheck_1">Снять отметки 1</button>
  <hr>
  <input type="checkbox" name="name" class="chb_2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="name" class="chb_2" />
  <button type="button" class="uncheck_2">Снять отметки 2</button>
</form>
```

**(*1)** `let num = ( e.target.className.match(/uncheck_(\d+)/) || [0,0] )[1];` — метод `match()` возвращает массив совпадений, если они есть ( пример: ["uncheck_2", "2"] ), или `null`, если ничего не нашлось. Хочется достать только число из нужного класса, но если кликнули не туда - будет ошибка *Cannot read property '1' of null*, поэтому добавлен второй массив `[0,0]` — возьмется он, если результат первого выражения будет null. В итоге в переменную `num` попадет или строка из нужного числа, или число `0`, которое не пройдет условие `if( num )`

P.s. см. → Регулярные выражения.

---

Но легче было бы чуть поменять разметку и не заморачиваться с числами:

```js
let uncheck = document.querySelectorAll('.uncheck');

uncheck.forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    let cbs = this.closest('div').querySelectorAll('.chb');
    cbs.forEach( cb => cb.checked = false );
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="bubu">
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="name" class="chb" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="name" class="chb" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="name" class="chb" />
    <button type="button" class="uncheck">Снять отметки 1</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="name" class="chb" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="name" class="chb" />
    <button type="button" class="uncheck">Снять отметки 2</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Спасибо, вариант который "формально" мне подошел больше всех предложенных. А не подскажете, как сделать, чтобы баттон uncheck_X появлялся только если хотя бы один чекбокс chb_Х отмечен? Учитывая, что отметки сохраняются и после отправки формы? Спасибо!

Comment: А зачем нод-лист в массив преобразовывать, если foreach умеет его перебирать?

Comment: @Alexashka Добавил в пример... Грубым перебором скрывает все кнопки, потом проходит по всем чекбоксам. Если в процессе у кого-то оказывается `cb.checked → true`, достает число из className - по этому числу находит кнопку и показывает её. А после отправки формы, можно повторно вызвать функцию `toggleUncheckBtns()`

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME все классно, но при клике на саму себя кнопка по логике вещей должна также самоликвидироваться, ведь чекбоксы сбрасываются)) если вас не затруднит, помогите с этим, пожалуйста

Comment: @Alexashka `display(e.target, 'none');` — в конце клика)

Answer (score 2):

Вот так:

```js
const uncheck_1 = document.querySelector(".uncheck_1");
const checkboxes = [...document.getElementsByClassName("chb_1")];

uncheck_1.addEventListener("click", () => {
  checkboxes.forEach(item => {
    item.checked = false;
  })
})

checkboxes.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("change", () => {
    if (item.checked === true) {
      uncheck_1.style.display = "block";
    }
  })
})
```

```css
.uncheck_1,
.uncheck_2 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="name" class="chb_1" value="value_1" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="name" class="chb_1" value="value_2" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="name" class="chb_1" value="value_3" />
  <button type="button" class="uncheck_1">Снять отметки 1</button>
  <input type="checkbox" name="name" class="chb_2" value="value_4" />
  <input type="checkbox" name="name" class="chb_2" value="value_5" />
  <button type="button" class="uncheck_2">Снять отметки 2</button>
</form>
```

Для второй кнопки аналогично

Comment: круто, спасибо! а не подскажете, как сделать чтобы кнопка сброса не показывалась, пока нет отмеченных чекбоксов в данной группе?

Comment: @Alexashka дописал код